# How to use $redact with Aggregation in Java with mongodb template

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm unable to add redact with mongodb template 
below is my mongo code which is working fine and using sping mongo 1.8.5

```
  db.abc.aggregate([
 { "$geoNear" : { near : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 72.5, 19.8 ] 
 }, distanceField: "dist.calculated", maxDistance: 500000, includeLocs: "dist.location", num: 5, limit: 200, spherical: true } },
{ "$unwind" : "$items" },
{ "$redact" : { 
"$cond" : { 
if : { "$eq" : [ { "$cmp" : [ "$items.address", "$dist.location" ] }, 0 ] },
then : "$$KEEP", 
else : "$$PRUNE"
 } 
} 
}
])
```

Here is my java code which is not working as above mongo code

```
 Point point=new Point(longi,lat);
    NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery.near(point).maxDistance(1000).spherical(true);
  Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.geoNear(nearQuery, "calculated"),Aggregation.unwind("items"),
    Aggregation.group("merchantId", "_id", "catalogTypeId", "catalogStatusId", "departmentName",
                        "categoryName", "subCategoryName", "serviceFlag", "date", "availability", "distance",
                        "commissionPercentage", "createdBy", "updatedBy", "departmentId", "categoryId",
                        "subCategoryId", "createdOn", "updatedOn").push("items").as("items"),
                Aggregation.skip(skip), Aggregation.limit(limit)

        );
```

can anybody help me to find out how to run this query in java

my document structure

> {
>       "_id" : "CAT106679778",
>       "_class" : "com.ikarma.core.catalog.domain.CatalogForAdminAndMerchant",
>       "merchantId" : "M117442443",
>       "catalogTypeId" : "catalogTypeProduct",
>       "catalogStatusId" : "catalogStatusDraft",
>       "items" : [
>           {
>               "name" : "Jewelry",
>               "description" : "Jewelry",
>               "price" : "1000",
>               "itemStatusId" : "catalogStatusDraft",
>               "itemStatusName" : "Draft",
>               "unitMeasure" : 30,
>               "stock" : NumberInt("12"),
>               "availableStock" : NumberInt("12"),
>               "orderStock" : NumberInt("0"),
>               "photos" : [
>                   "https://clappilystorage.blob.core.windows.net/clappilymerchant/M117442443/MyProduct/GiftsAnniversary GiftsJewelryJewelry/1520415128722cheers.jpg"
>               ],
>               "activeFlag" : "undefined",
>               "tags" : [
>                   "Jewelry",
>                   "Jewelry"
>               ],
>               "discount" : "25",
>               "advancePayment" : "10",
>               "unitName" : "Gm",
>               "itemId" : NumberLong("78921671000"),
>               "videos" : [
>                   null,
>                   null,
>                   null
>               ],
>               "commissionPercentage" : 10,
>               "commissionAmount" : 0,
>               "itemIsDeleted" : "false",
>               "netSellingPrice" : 750,
>               "starCount" : 0,
>               "deliveryCharges" : 0,
>               "customItemCode" : "zdfg",
>               "taxes" : 0,
>               "perishable" : false,
>               "itemsLat" : 21,
>               "itemsLong" : 74,
>               "ratingAvg" : 0,
>               "address" : {
>                   "type" : "Point",
>                   "coordinates" : [
>                       74,
>                       21
>                   ]
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "name" : "Jewelry",
>               "description" : "Jewelry",
>               "price" : "1000",
>               "itemStatusId" : "catalogStatusDraft",
>               "itemStatusName" : "Draft",
>               "unitMeasure" : 30,
>               "stock" : NumberInt("12"),
>               "availableStock" : NumberInt("12"),
>               "orderStock" : NumberInt("0"),
>               "photos" : [
>                   "https://clappilystorage.blob.core.windows.net/clappilymerchant/M117442443/MyProduct/GiftsAnniversary GiftsJewelryJewelry/1520415128722cheers.jpg"
>               ],
>               "activeFlag" : "undefined",
>               "tags" : [
>                   "Jewelry",
>                   "Jewelry"
>               ],
>               "discount" : "25",
>               "advancePayment" : "10",
>               "unitName" : "Gm",
>               "itemId" : NumberLong("1347268704"),
>               "videos" : [
>                   null,
>                   null,
>                   null
>               ],
>               "commissionPercentage" : 10,
>               "commissionAmount" : 0,
>               "itemIsDeleted" : "false",
>               "netSellingPrice" : 750,
>               "starCount" : 0,
>               "deliveryCharges" : 0,
>               "customItemCode" : "zdfg",
>               "taxes" : 0,
>               "perishable" : false,
>               "itemsLat" : 22,
>               "itemsLong" : 75,
>               "ratingAvg" : 0,
>               "address" : {
>                   "type" : "Point",
>                   "coordinates" : [
>                       75,
>                       22
>                   ]
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "name" : "Jewelry",
>               "description" : "Jewelry",
>               "price" : "1000",
>               "itemStatusId" : "catalogStatusDraft",
>               "itemStatusName" : "Draft",
>               "unitMeasure" : 30,
>               "stock" : NumberInt("12"),
>               "availableStock" : NumberInt("12"),
>               "orderStock" : NumberInt("0"),
>               "photos" : [
>                   "https://clappilystorage.blob.core.windows.net/clappilymerchant/M117442443/MyProduct/GiftsAnniversary GiftsJewelryJewelry/1520415128722cheers.jpg"
>               ],
>               "activeFlag" : "undefined",
>               "tags" : [
>                   "Jewelry",
>                   "Jewelry"
>               ],
>               "discount" : "25",
>               "advancePayment" : "10",
>               "unitName" : "Gm",
>               "itemId" : NumberLong("10043410600"),
>               "videos" : [
>                   null,
>                   null,
>                   null
>               ],
>               "commissionPercentage" : 10,
>               "commissionAmount" : 0,
>               "itemIsDeleted" : "false",
>               "netSellingPrice" : 750,
>               "starCount" : 0,
>               "deliveryCharges" : 0,
>               "customItemCode" : "zdfg",
>               "taxes" : 0,
>               "perishable" : false,
>               "itemsLat" : 23,
>               "itemsLong" : 76,
>               "ratingAvg" : 0,
>               "address" : {
>                   "type" : "Point",
>                   "coordinates" : [
>                       76,
>                       23
>                   ]
>               }
>           }
>       ],
>       "departmentName" : "Gifts",
>       "categoryName" : "Anniversary Gifts",
>       "subCategoryName" : "Jewelry",
>       "serviceFlag" : "",
>       "updatedBy" : [
>           {
>               "_id" : "M117442443",
>               "name" : "Sales Team"
>           }
>       ],
>       "createdBy" : [
>           {
>               "_id" : "M117442443",
>               "name" : "Sales Team"
>           }
>       ],
>       "departmentId" : "5948c14be4b0d3372e47423d",
>       "categoryId" : "5948cc1fe4b0d3372e474287",
>       "catalogIsDeleted" : "false",
>       "subCategoryId" : "5948cd46e4b0d3372e474291",
>       "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-03-07T15:03:34.877+05:30"),
>       "updatedOn" : ISODate("2018-03-08T13:09:53.373+05:30"),
>       "availability" : [
>           {
>               "startTime" : "null",
>               "endTime" : "null"
>           },
>           {
>               "startTime" : "null",
>               "endTime" : "null"
>           },
>           {
>               "startTime" : "null",
>               "endTime" : "null"
>           }
>       ],
>       "distance" : "0",
>       "merchantStatus" : "Accepted"
>          }

thank you

Comment: What is your mongo server version and spring mongo jar version ?

Comment: @Veeram mongo server version is 3.4.9  and spring data mongo  is 1.8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AggregationOperation` to build `$redact` aggregation stage.

You will need 1.8.5 version.

```
AggregationOperation redactOperation = aggregationOperationContext -> {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    BasicDBObject cmp =  new BasicDBObject("$cmp", Arrays.asList( "$items.address","$dist.location"));
    map.put("if", new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.asList(cmp, 0)));
    map.put("then", "$$KEEP");
    map.put("else", "$$PRUNE");
    return new BasicDBObject("$redact", new BasicDBObject("$cond", map));
};

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.geoNear(nearQuery, "calculated"), 
    Aggregation.unwind("items"),
    redactOperation,
    Aggregation.skip(skip), 
    Aggregation.limit(limit)
);
```

Comment: m using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb , and  by using above java code m not getting any o/p where as in mongo shell m getting proper output

Comment: Can I see your code ? Here is my generated query `{ "$redact" : { "$cond" : { "if" : { "$eq" : [{ "$cmp" : ["$items.address", "$dist.location"] }, 0] }, "then" : "$$KEEP", "else" : "$$PRUNE" } } }` . compare with yours. Please make sure you are on 1.8.5 as well.

Comment: Did you include dist.location in the group stage ?